# *.stackoverflow.com with answers, suggestions, examples, and no questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, answers

I think it would be great to have a *.stackoverflow.com with answers only and no questions.
Ok, not really answers, but suggestions.
For example "I found a great way to do this, or I made this workaround for that bug, etc"
Wouldn't it be cool?

Stackoverflow is great when you are faced with a problem and need a solution, but what I propose, will not solve problems immediately but will feed your imagination with things you may never had wondered.

Comment: Phrase a question around and self-answer it. Or get a blog!

Comment: Something like tips.stackoverflow.com?  A place to leave tips for different languages, IDE's, etc. would be nice.  I'm not sure the Q&A format of stackoverflow would work very well for that.

Comment: Well, about the SO format, I think it just fits perfectly.
See, instead of posting a question, you just post your tip. Then what now are the answers, are just suggestions, fixes, opinions, comments, etc.

Anyway, I see a great reluctance to change here, it's like some are afraid that SO changes from what it is now. That's not gonna happen, of course, and I don't want it to change, because we're all here because of how good SO currently is.

I'm just proposing alternatives. And you're right, I should get off my butt and do it. Maybe someday. I have a stack of many other ideas too..

Answer (score 9):

It's called "StackOverflow Jeopardy!".  Just post your suggestion by identifying the problem your suggestion solves, asking that question, and then supplying your suggestion as an answer.

It's also common etiquette to make the question — or at least your answer — community wiki to avoid the appearance of begging rep.

Answer (score 7):

Turning a Q&A engine into an A engine...

I don't think this has future

Comment: Ha, good way to put it.

Comment: We could turn it into an A&Q engine -- you post your [whatever], and then people can start asking "What's the point?". Just swap the names "Question" and "Answer" in the engine.

Comment: Kinda like answering **42** and figuring out the question later

Comment: (and I swear it's not edited)

Answer (score 3):

What is with this compulsive desire to warp SO into every different thing imaginable?  StackOverflow is a *question* and answer site; this goes against the very point of it.  Can't we just appreciate SO for what it is and does well?

If you really want a site like this, Jeff would tell you to [get off your butt](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000135.html) and do it.

Answer (score 2):

Boy there seems to have been a lot of talk lately about changing the StackExchange sites into things they're not. This suggestion, the "ability to purchase rep for bounty" question, etc.

I'm against most of it. Don't get me wrong, some of the individual ideas are neat -- including this one -- but the right answer **isn't** the official StackExchange-based LOJ sites. For this specific suggestion, the right answer is -- as others have mentioned -- a blog, or a license of StackExchange and build it yourself. (Heck, they might even make you a member of the ever-growing LOJ!)

These communities (S[OFU]) are all based on Q&A -- take the Q out, and you have essentially a wiki-based blog/forum. While that concept is fairly cool, it isn't what these sites are for, and ultimately (I think) would dilute the quality of these sites.

Answer (score 2):

Many SO users already have blogs.  Visit the profile pages of users whose answers you find particularly helpful/insightful and see if they have one listed.

Answer (score 2):

I think [Mayor Adam West](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_Guy) best explains the value questions give to answers:

> [An answer without a question is a statement.](http://www.imdb.com/video/hulu/vi4009623577/)