# Knowledge Overflow

Tags: feature-request

I was thinking to myself, "I know a lot of things. I would like to share that information with a lot of people."

Are there any plans for a Stack Overflow family site for knowledge sharing? Sometimes people aren't in the mood or wont ask a question. Sometimes they would rather just put that knowledge out there for other people to share.

It's just an idea I had for another site. I'm not sure if there's any duplication with other SOFU sites.

Comment: I learned lot from you @Random , Thanks .. Nice Edit :-)

Comment: I thought to myself, "I know a lot of things" once, too. Then, I went to college, and that thought has disappeared, never to be seen again.

Comment: @Eric .. I am also having the same thought about " I know a lot of things " , but @Random Edited in that way . actually  " I want mention , I want share my knowledge "

Comment: Sounds like a dupe to me:http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14211/-stackoverflow-com-with-answers-suggestions-examples-and-no-questions

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Start a blog instead.

Comment: But it wont belong to SO family

Comment: The information will be out there. You then just "get popular" and no need to ask a question. Or just go with http://stackExchange.com and post rhetorical questions.

Comment: +1. I even think Larry and Sergey at Google have thought of a way to measure your blog rep.

Comment: @random Blogs don't provide the same opportunity for collaboration that SO does. There's also a greater barrier you have to cross in order for people to even see any knowledge you shared.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds to me like you just described [Wikipedia](http://www.wikipedia.org/).

Comment: not like wiki

Answer (score 4):

There has been some consent that you could also somewhat play jeopardy: asking a question that you then could answer yourself. You just have to preserve the Q&A format, when you want it to be on the SO family.

SO/SF/SU want to be a repository for knowledge.

Comment: This is in fact encouraged, because it is not a monologue.  If you present bad information, or if a better solution/technique exists, the others can point this out.  The entire community benefits, and what started as you teaching others might even end up with you learning something new.  Why *wouldn't* you want to do it this way?

Answer (score 2):

Here is answer for you, maybe.

**Moving a personal technical blog to stackoverflow / serverfault**

- [Posting and answering questions you have already found the answer to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/moving-a-personal-technical-blog-to-stackoverflow-serverfault)